# Beaglebone packet sniffer using LWIP and StarterWare

Tags: beagleboneblack, packet-sniffers, bare-metal, lwip

I have been working on a project where I am planning on using the BeagleBone Black as a packet sniffer (and logger) for a local network.  I have worked with the Starterware examples echo_server and http_server, and those work fine.  However, not being very well acquainted with the inner operations of TCP/IP I don't know how to modify the existing Starterware code base to implement promiscuous mode packet sniffing.  Does anybody have any suggestions or reasons why this port of LWIP may or may not work for the intended use?
Thanks,

Comment: I understand that the ALE (Address Lookup Engine) needs to be bypassed on the AM335x and that is simple enough to do.  However, I am still not seeing RX interrupts happening from any other packets than those that are sent directly to the BBB or broadcasted. Apparently there is something else needed as well to allow those packets not directed to the BBB to make it through the PHY.  Any help?

Comment: I am supplying the zipped project folder that has the project in question in hopes somebody will take a look at it.  All I have read is that ALE needs to be bypassed, but apparently there is something more that need to happen to send the packet on. Here is the link.    https://www.dropbox.com/s/fznycn85xb68374/EnetExample.zip?dl=0